# Which tests of German language knowledge are best accepted in the business world?

Tags: proficiency-test

I'm looking to be specific about my German language skills on my resume and I'm curious which of the various tests are best respected in a business setting. Also, is there any difference between the countries where German is spoken? That is, is one test better accepted in Germany and one test better accepted in Austria for example?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Europäischer Referenzrahmen](https://www.europaeischer-referenzrahmen.de/deutsch-sprachzertifikate.php) there is not much choice:

- Goethe-Institute or
- TELC

The latter is not very well-known yet, so I would settle for Goethe-Institut.
Their tests are also harmonized with Swiss/Austria, so I expect no different ranking there.

Answer (score 1):

These tests/the resulting certifications all have international recognition, and as such they must be accepted in both Germany and Austria. (Also, once you have passed a test, the certification is yours. I recommend putting all your language certifications on your resume--you earned them!)

The Goethe-Institut is probably the most well-known for these tests.

Austria has an equivalent set of exams, known as the ÖSD: https://www.osd.at/en/ They also have international recognition and they are created to meet the same standards.

The ÖSD provides a couple of additional variations for these kinds of tests:

- A1, A2, B1 certifications specific to Austria (for people who want to move there specifically)
- a C2 examination including Business German: https://www.osd.at/en/exams/oesd-exams/oesd-zertifikat-c2-wirtschaftssprache-deutsch-zc2-wd/